# Android Studio purpose of support library

Tags: android

Sorry if this may seem trivial, but all Google gave me were links on how to add the support library. What is the purpose of the support library? For example, I had to use a CursorAdapter, but there were 2 different libraries that had it, android.widget and android.support.v4.widget. What is the difference between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: To support some capability from higher API to lower API. Something likes universal support for each android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an excerpt taken from [Understanding Android Support Library](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/) article, kudos to **Josh Hight**.

**Why?**
One of the great strengths of the Android platform is its support for a huge number and variety of devices. From your handset, tablet, and smartwatch to your television, car, and beyond, Android wants to be the all-purpose mobile computing platform. In terms of numbers, this approach has been very successful – there are likely more than 20,000 distinct devices at the time of this writing. That’s far more than any competing platforms.

Supporting all these devices, though, poses a couple of challenges. Users expect apps to function consistently on every device, despite significant differences in hardware and software. Meanwhile, because of unique challenges in delivering Android software updates to users, developers cannot always depend on users having access to the latest Android releases. In fact, developers should anticipate most of their users to be running releases that are 18 months old or older.

Without help from the Android team, developers would be forced to make some pretty ugly compromises in order to support most of their users. Fortunately, the Android team recognized that accommodating older devices and releases was strategically important. However, doing this in a way that doesn’t hamstring future releases presents an architectural challenge because the Android APIs obviously need to evolve over time. How can important new APIs be made available to the majority of Android users and not just those with newer devices lucky enough to run the latest releases?

The answer is one of the most important and peculiar design decisions made by the Android team: the Android Support Library.

**When should I use the Android Support Library?**
You should use one of the support libraries when you need specific framework features that are newer than the minSdkVersion of your app or that are not available in the standard framework.
However, Google considers the general use of the support libraries to be a best practice, even if not necessarily required.

---

Excerpt from [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html):

> Support libraries allow apps running on older versions of the Android
>   platform to support features made available on newer versions of the
>   platform. For example, an app running on a version of Android lower
>   than 5.0 (API level 21) that relies on framework classes cannot
>   display material-design elements, as that version of the Android
>   framework doesn't support material design. However, if the app
>   incorporates the Support Library's [appcompat
>   library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html),
>   the app has access to many of the features available in API level 21,
>   including support for material design. As a result, your app can
>   deliver a more consistent experience across a broader range of
>   platform versions.

Comment: Great answer! Also, since using support libraries is best practice, does that mean I should always use the support library, if it exists for that particular class, over the standard one?

Comment: No, you don't need to always use support library. For example, if you  need to support android with API Level > 21 only, you don't need use support library. Though you can't access the newer API Level capability.

Comment: Or if you only need to create app  with no fancy UI, like system app, or using default framework UI, you don't need to use support library. Support API tend to increase your app size about 1-2 Mb. But please take a note that some old API has been deprecated in the newer API.